# Control documented type signature of re-exported function

Tags: haskell, module, export, ghci, haddock

Suppose there is a library module `Foo` which is not under my control:

```
module Foo (Foo, thing) where
data Foo = Foo Int
thing :: Foo
thing = Foo 3
```

Now suppose I have my own library module, which re-exports `thing` from the `Foo` module.

```
module Bar (Foo.thing, getBar) where
import qualified Foo
type Bar = Foo.Foo
getBar :: Bar -> Int
getBar (Foo i) = i
```

For compatibility reasons, I do *not* want to export a different `thing`. I want to make sure I export `Foo.thing`, so that if the user imports both the `Foo` and `Bar` modules, they will get the same `thing` and there will not be a name clash.

Now suppose we have a third module that uses `Bar`.

```
module Main where
import Bar
```

Let's load the third into ghci.

```
[1 of 3] Compiling Foo              ( Foo.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 3] Compiling Bar              ( Bar.hs, interpreted )
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main, Bar, Foo.
ghci> :t thing
thing :: Foo.Foo
ghci> :t getBar
getBar :: Bar -> Int
ghci> getBar thing
3
ghci> :info Bar
type Bar = Foo.Foo  -- Defined at Bar.hs:3:6-8
```

Instead of ghci and the haddocks indicating that `thing` in module `Bar` has type `Foo.Foo`, I'd like it to state that `thing` has type `Bar`. Is there any way to make this happen without exporting a different `thing`?

Comment: Wait, wouldn't there be a clash if the user imports both modules?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez try adding `import Foo` to the third file, and see for yourself! (there's not a clash since they both export *the same* `thing`.) In the event that both are imported, I would *still* like to tell ghci to prefer `Bar` over `Foo`.

Comment: WOW!  How long has that feature been available!?!?!  This changes EVERYTHING.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez: since always :) if you think about the number of things defined in the standard library and re-exported in the Prelude, you use this feature all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I hear evidence to the contrary, the answer seems to be: **you can't**.